# Crystal report muti-value parameter value in header

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports

Currently using the latest Crystal reports,

I have a numeric parameter with strings as the description, and want to have the parameters selected, to be displayed in the header.

Currently my formula only displayed the numeric values and not the description of the parameter.

My formula is:

```
   NumberVar i;
StringVar Array aStatuses; 

for i:= 1 to Ubound({?aSTATUS}) Do 
(
        Redim Preserve aStatuses[i];
        aStatuses[i] := totext({?aSTATUS},0)[i];
);

Join (aStatuses,", ");
```

The aSTATUS parameter of mine have this values:

> Value: 7 Description: Current
>
> Value: 11 Description: Overdue

So, if i selected both or any of them, then the description must be displayed not the numeric value. What am i doing wrong?

My parameter screenshot, currently only 7 and 11 is pulling through in the header:

[image]

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to split the final output

try this:

```
Split(str [3 to Length(str)]," ")[3] & " "& Split(str [3 to Length(str)]," ")[4]
```

place above code as last line of the formula

Comment: I now get an error: " A subscript must be between 1 and the size of the array"

Comment: if this is the string `Value: 7 Description: Current` you are getting as outpur of `Split(str [3 to Length(str)]," ")[3]` then this formula should work you can also try using `[2] and [3]` instead of `[3] and [4]`. if not post exact output of `Split(str [3 to Length(str)]," ")[3]`

Comment: Whether I change to formula according to your suggestions, i still get the same message: " A subscript must be between 1 and the size of the array "

Comment: [3] and [4] changed to [1] and [3] then the error dissapeared as it's the size of my array. Now results are appearing, but only a single numeric value instead of the string values

Comment: I tried to do the following as well:  @Siva NumberVar i;
StringVar Array aStatuses; 

for i:= 1 to Ubound({?aSTATUS}) Do 
(
        Redim Preserve aStatuses[i];
        aStatuses[i] := {?aSTATUS}[i];
);

Join (aStatuses,", ");

Comment: Is it worked for you? or do you want to check your formula? Also if you thik this answer is heloful aceept it as answer so that others can use

Comment: nothing is working at the moment, im still getting numeric values instead of the strings.

Comment: please update your question with what is the output of the formula and what you are expecting.. will try to answer

Comment: question updated with another formula a tried, but getting an error "Array must be subscripted" I understand there are more than one way of have the description displaying instead of the numeric values. @Siva

Comment: Actually `Redim Preserve aStatuses[i]` is not necessary instead you can just use `aStatuses[i] := aStatuses[i]+totext({?aSTATUS},0)[i]+",";` and in last step you need to change as `Join (aStatuses);`

Comment: i have made the neccesary changes to my formula as pointed out by you, however I get a message now "The Array must be subscripted"

Comment: sorry didn't notice there is a bug in your formula try this `aStatuses := aStatuses+totext({?aSTATUS}[i],0);`

Comment: thank you the error is gone now. However the numeric values are still displaying. Here is a screenshot of my Status parameter, only values 7 and 1 are being pulled through on the header still, instead of the descirption: http://s32.postimg.org/evy1qh7v9/status.png

Comment: I can't open the link.. can you post the screenshot in question itself

Comment: Ok in value of parameter window you need both value and description?

Comment: I just need the description to show on the header of the report. Thank you

Comment: Today is dayoff for me will post answer tomorrow

Comment: Problem here is though you select the descrition since there is a numeric value in value column there are only numbers displayed in header... So if you need to display comments then you need to take description in value column of parameters

Comment: that is correct, however the value column's numeric values are referencing to a column in the database. All my fields are pulled in via a SQL function. I need the values intact as they reference to the description in the database as well

Comment: one way is to use subreport... pass the parameter to subreport there retrive the corresponding values for the returned list and display in header.